# Jmeter XSD validation stopped at first error

Tags: xml, validation, jmeter, xsd-validation, assertion

I am using XML schema validation to validate XML response against XSD schema.
Problem is that XML validation is stopped after first error found.

For example, i have one error at line 105 and second at line 1200
It returns only error at line 105, then i have to fix this, or add value to XSD schema, only then(second run) i can see error at line 1200.

Is it possible to see all errors in one report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XML Schema Assertion - unfortunately no, you'll have to write XML validation code in [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) or [JSR223 Assertion](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance).

See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/17807/6225 answer for details.